# Webforms Repeater Link Question

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, repeater, linkbutton

I have a repeater that has a LinkButton in one of its columns and I have the onclick event wired up.  When the user clicks on one of the options, I need to know in the event which LinkButton they clicked on.  What is the best practice to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `OnCommand` event instead of `OnClick` use some `CommandName` and `CommandArgument` to distinguish b/w items. [This MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.oncommand.aspx) has an example.

Answer (score 3):

Normally `CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Id")` is used for such purpose

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" 
CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Id") %>' CommandName="commandName"></asp:LinkButton>
```

and then it will be like...

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.CommandName == "commandName")
    {
       Int32 id = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is wire up the Repeater's `ItemCommand` event and not use the LinkButton's `OnClick` event. Instead wire up the `CommandName` of the LinkButton.

When the ItemCommand fires you'll be able to tell what button triggered it based on the `CommandName` that was set on the button. You'll also have access to all the controls in that row of the Repeater.

MSDN
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemcommand.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check with this code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            repTriggers.DataSource = new int[3] { 0, 1, 2 };
            repTriggers.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void repTriggers_ItemCommand(object sender, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "trigger")
        {
            LinkButton btn = e.CommandSource as LinkButton;

            if (btn != null)
            {
                lblUpdate.Text = "Update triggered by " + btn.ID + e.Item.ItemIndex.ToString();
            }

            // [Steve] removed UpdatePanel2.Update()
        }
    }
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="TheScriptManager" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

    <%-- [Steve] removed UpdatePanel1 --%>    
    <asp:Repeater ID="repTriggers" runat="server" OnItemCommand="repTriggers_ItemCommand">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkTrigger" runat="server" Text="Trigger" CommandName="trigger"></asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="conditional">
        <%-- [Steve] added repTriggers as an AsyncPostBackTrigger --%>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="repTriggers" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblUpdate" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Source URL http://forums.asp.net/p/1062060/1528071.aspx